# Есть название у "такой" операции произведения векторов?

Tags: математика, геометрия, терминология

Получаю вектор путем произведения двух единичных векторов. Складываю их так как складывают косинусы и синусы.

```
v3.x = v1.x * v2.x - v1.y * v2.y
v3.y = v1.y * v2.x + v1.x * v2.y
```

Есть ли у этой операции название в контексте векторов?

Answer (score 6):

**[Комплексное умножение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE#.D0.90.D0.BB.D0.B3.D0.B5.D0.B1.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.B5.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D1.84.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.BC.D0.B0)** примерно так и выглядит.

```
(a + ib)(c + id) = (ac - bd) + i(bc + ad)
...где i - мнимая единица, для которой i^2 = -1
```

...которое в [геометрической модели](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE#.D0.93.D0.B5.D0.BE.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.82.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.B5.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D0.BC.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B5.D0.BB.D1.8C) для векторов (на комплексной плоскости) единичной длины даёт другой вектор единичной длины, аргумент которого (угол с Re+, горизонтальной осью "вправо") является суммой аргументов составляющих.

Если бы они были не единичными, длина результата была бы произведением их длин.

Answer (score 1):

Подозреваю, что названия нет, т.к. операция несимметричная - для X вы считаете разницу квадратов (похоже на скалярное произведение, только знак не тот), а для Y - кросс продукт (и опять знак не тот).

---

Интересно, а как вы пришли к этой формуле и как используете результаты ее вычисления? Может быть это 2 несвязанных параметра и знаки не те - тогда это просто скалярное и векторное произведения.

Comment: Она таки симметричная (на вещественных числах во всяком случае). В разности участвуют произведения разных компонент векторов. Если поменять вектора местами, поменяется только порядок в произведениях, но не результат.

Comment: @D-side меня смущает то, что она не симметричная относительно x/y. В любом случае, хотелось бы получить уточнения от автора вопроса - возможно они прольют свет на термин который нужен.

Comment: Ну, это как раз нормально. Числовое представление вектора на плоскости это ж **упорядоченная** пара чисел. Да, лучше подождать ТСа.